# Updating satellite assembly without re-compiling

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resources, satellite-assembly

I have a Class Library project that is used by many other web applications. I want to create a satellite assemblies for that class library. I don't want to have to recompile / redeploy the class library when I change one of the resource strings.

While I think I understand the concept of satellite assembly, I don't understand how to build it so that I can use it the way I want.

By default, when you add a resource file to a project in Visual Studio, it sets its build action to "Embedded Resource".

So, my project is called `MyProject`. I have a default resource file called `MyProject.Resources.resx` and another one called `MyProject.Resources.fr.resx`.

When I build, all I get is `MyProject.dll` and a "fr" subfolder with `MyProject.resources.dll`.

So the way I understand it is that the main assembly (MyProject.dll) contains the default resources because it is set as embedded resource. However, I can't update the resources without redeploying the whole assembly which isn't good for me.

I read on MSDN about packaging assemblies using AL.exe but I still don't understand :

How do I set visual studio so that it outputs my resource files as separate files from the main assembly? From what I read on MSDN, I need .resource files but i'm not quite sure.

Once I do get it the way I want, what would I do if I wanted to modify a resource file? I suppose I would update the resource in visual studio, build the project and copy only the resource DLLs on the target server, is that correct? Would I be able to copy them directly in the GAC along with `MyProject.dll` and everything would still work fine?

Thanks!